# Proofs of basilar powers identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

We all know that a simple and intuitive way to show what $2^n$ is (for $n$ an integer number) is to write it as

$$2^n = \underbrace{2\times 2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2}_{n\ \text{times}}$$

My question is: what is the most intuitive method to show the meaning of these two identities?

$$2^{-n} = \frac{1}{2^n}$$
$$2^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sqrt[n]{2}$$

Comment: Well... what do you mean with 'show what $2^n$' is. For positive $n$ it is defined as what you write.
And what is your definition of $2^n$ when $n$ is a negative integer and $2^{1/n}$ for positive integers? Most people learn what you write as definitions of these powers. Of course these definitions aren't just arbitrary, they are chosen to fit together well, but there is no meaning behind the identities that define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting point to justify (not really a proof) the two formulas in OP is to start from a good definition of the positive integer power of a number $a$. The better that I know is a

> recursive definition:
>   $$
> a^0=1 \qquad a^n=a \times a^{n-1} \qquad a \in \mathbb{R} \quad n \in \mathbb{N}
> $$

from this definition we can easily see that this *exponential* function has the property:
$$
(1) \qquad \qquad a^{n+m}=a^na^m
$$
that implies
$$
(2) \qquad \qquad (a^n)^m=a^{n\times m}
$$
now we want to extend the definition to exponents in $\mathbb{Q}$ in such a way that the properties $(1)$ and $(2)$ are always true. So, we have:
$$
a^0=a^{n+(-n)}=a^na^{-n}=1
$$
and this means that $a^{-n}$ have to be inverse of $a^n$.

Also, if $t=\dfrac{m}{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have:

$$
a^{n \times t}=a^m \iff (a^t)^n=a^m
$$
and this means, by definition of the radical, that
$$
a^t=a^{\frac{m}{n}}=\sqrt[n]{a^m}
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the first relation

$$2^{n}=\underbrace{2\times 2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2}_{n\ \text{times}}=\underbrace{2\times 2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2}_{n-1\ \text{times}}\times2=2^{n-1}\times2.$$

Then $$2^{n-1}=\frac{2^n}2,\\
2^{n-2}=\frac{2^n}{2^2},\\
\cdots\\
2^{n-m}=\frac{2^n}{2^m}.$$

By the first relation
$$2^{nm} = \underbrace{2\times 2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2}_{nm\ \text{times}}=\underbrace{\underbrace{2\times 2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2}_{n\ \text{times}}\times \underbrace{2\times 2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2}_{n\ \text{times}}\cdots \underbrace{2\times 2\times 2\times \cdots \times 2}_{n\ \text{times}}}_{m\text{ times}}\\
=(2^n)^m$$
 and

$$\sqrt[m]{2^{nm}}=2^n=2^{nm/m},$$ or
$$\sqrt[m]{2^p}=2^{p/m}.$$

Comment: That was awesome!